# Pattern recognition for data alignement and data difference

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, difference

I have some data that can be used as "reference" and I'd like to realigned new data using the reference.
Let's say I have this:

[image]

and I want to compare it to

[image]

I would like to be able to recognize patterns and be able realign it and knowing what's new (has been added) and what has been deleted:

[image]

Here my data are in numbers for easier explanation but in fact, each number is a structure composed of more than one information (for instance: length, width, type).
What kind of algorithm should I use to do that ? Could you give me some pointers: algorithm name, libraries I can use...

Thank you.

Comment: You can know what was changed by using a diff algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Levenshtein algorithm for compute minimal editing sequence, transforms one string to another. See: http://www.let.rug.nl/kleiweg/lev/